# Looking for an equivalent to MATLAB's bitshift() in C++ with or without Eigen

Tags: c++, matlab, eigen

As the Title states, looking for a means of replicating the MATLAB 'bitshift' and 'bitand' functions in C++.

I'm translating from Matlab to C++... the code in MATLAB is being implemented like this:

```
c= unit8(bitshift(input, -10);
d= uint16(bitand(bitshift(input, -5), 65535));
```

How can I do this in C++, with or without Eigen.

Comment: There are operators for this in C++. What has your research turned up?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [left and right shift opertors](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/left-shift-right-shift-operators-c-cpp/) in place of `bitshift` and [the "bitwise and" operator](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bitwise-operators-in-c-cpp/) in place of `bitand`. The diference is that the MATLAB version can work on arrays, but you can just loop in the C++ code.

Maybe Eigen has similar functionality to compute these operations on whole arrays, but even if it does not have that, it probably has a way to access the memory where the array elements are stored. You can use that to compute "bit shift" and "bit and" using C++ operators and it should be really fast.